# Pyspark dataframe process each row based on set of rows from the same dateframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, row

Below piece of code works fine for smaller dataframe as it will bring all data to driver memory but I want to leverage distributed computing of spark. Can someone help me on how to leverage Pyspark capabilities

```
def topNSuggestion(row, noSuggestionLabel, n):
    #create output suggestion list
    suggestion = [noSuggestionLabel] * n
    
    #Create data frame for row received as an input to this method
    suggestedNameDataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'name':row.index})
    suggestedCountDataFrame = pd.DataFrame([eachRow for eachRow in row.values], columns=['countOrder','countQuantity'])
    suggestedNameCountDataFrame = pd.concat([suggestedNameDataFrame,suggestedCountDataFrame], axis=1)
    
    #Sort suggestion data frame on number of orders and quantity
    sortSuggestedNameCountDataFrame = suggestedNameCountDataFrame.sort_values(by=['countOrder','countQuantity'], ascending=False)
    sortSuggestedNameCountDataFrame =  sortSuggestedNameCountDataFrame.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    countProduct = sortSuggestedNameCountDataFrame.shape[0]
    
    #Update suggestion list only if number of orders are more than zero else NO suggestions 
    countSuggestion = 0
    while(countSuggestion < countProduct and countSuggestion < n):
        if sortSuggestedNameCountDataFrame.countOrder[countSuggestion] > 0:
            suggestion[countSuggestion] = str(sortSuggestedNameCountDataFrame.name[countSuggestion])
        countSuggestion += 1
    return suggestion
```

My main code to process each row in dataframe. I am using dataframe.collect method which mitigates benefits of distributed computing.

```
noSuggestionLabel = 'No Suggestion'
numberOfSuggestions = 5
#create product suggest data frame 
customerProductSuggestDataFrame = aggregateQuantityFilterDataFrame.drop_duplicates(['CustomerId', 'ProductId', 'ProductName'])
customerProductSuggestDataFrame = customerProductSuggestDataFrame.drop('STORE_NUMBER', 'OrderId', 'AmountPurchased', 'ProductCode')
customerProductSuggestDataFrame = customerProductSuggestDataFrame.sort('CustomerId','ProductId')

for i in range(numberOfSuggestions):
  suggestion = 'Suggestion' + str(i+1) + 'ItemDescription'
  customerProductSuggestDataFrame = customerProductSuggestDataFrame.withColumn(suggestion, F.lit(noSuggestionLabel))
  
previousCustomerId = 0

#Process each product suggestion
customerProductSuggestDataFrameCollect = customerProductSuggestDataFrame.collect()
for eachCustomerProductSuggest in customerProductSuggestDataFrameCollect:
  if previousCustomerId != eachCustomerProductSuggest.CustomerId:
    currentCustomerId = eachCustomerProductSuggest.CustomerId
    #Filter customer level purchase history info
    eachCustomerAggregateQuantityDataFrame = aggregateQuantityFilterDataFrame.filter(aggregateQuantityFilterDataFrame.CustomerId == eachCustomerProductSuggest.CustomerId)
    #Create product matrix for each customer
    #Get all unqiue product code from store purchase history info for this customer 
    uniqueProducts = list(eachCustomerAggregateQuantityDataFrame.select('ProductId').distinct().toPandas()['ProductId'])
    uniqueProducts.sort()
    #create product ranking data frame with rows and columns as unique product code only
    productDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(index=uniqueProducts,columns=uniqueProducts)
    for index,eachRow in productDataFrame.iterrows():
      for col in productDataFrame.columns:
          productDataFrame[index][col] = dict({'countOrder': 0, 'countQuantity':0})
    
    previousOrderId = 0
    eachCustomerAggregateQuantityDataFrameCollect = eachCustomerAggregateQuantityDataFrame.collect()
    for eachCustomerOrderAggr in eachCustomerAggregateQuantityDataFrameCollect:
      if previousOrderId != eachCustomerOrderAggr.OrderId:
        productQuantityDict = {}
        previousOrderId = eachCustomerOrderAggr.OrderId
      
      #Iterate through all products to process previous products in the same order
      for previousProductOrder in productQuantityDict:
        #Only if not same product
        if previousProductOrder != eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId:                    
          #Update number of orders for each product in product matrix
          productDataFrame.loc[eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId,previousProductOrder]['countOrder'] = productDataFrame.loc[eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId,previousProductOrder]['countOrder'] + 1
          productDataFrame.loc[previousProductOrder,eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId]['countOrder'] = productDataFrame.loc[previousProductOrder,eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId]['countOrder'] + 1
          #Update quantity for each product in product matrix
          productDataFrame.loc[eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId,previousProductOrder]['countQuantity'] = productDataFrame.loc[eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId,previousProductOrder]['countQuantity'] + productQuantityDict[previousProductOrder]
          productDataFrame.loc[previousProductOrder,eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId]['countQuantity'] = productDataFrame.loc[previousProductOrder,eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId]['countQuantity'] + eachCustomerOrderAggr.AmountPurchased
      #Add product that is processed to product list
      productQuantityDict[eachCustomerOrderAggr.ProductId] = eachCustomerOrderAggr.AmountPurchased
      
    #Create dataframe with top n suggestions for each product
    productSuggestion = productDataFrame.apply(lambda row:topNSuggestion(row, noSuggestionLabel, n=numberOfSuggestions), axis=1)
  
  #Add Suggestions created for each ProductId to current customer
  if currentCustomerId == eachCustomerProductSuggest.CustomerId:  
    eachSuggestionList = productSuggestion.loc[eachCustomerProductSuggest.ProductId]
    #Append suggestions to product suggestion data frame
    count = 1
    for eachSuggestion in eachSuggestionList:
      suggestion = 'Suggestion' + str(count) + 'ItemDescription'
      if eachSuggestion != noSuggestionLabel:
        eachSuggestionProductName = productInfoDataFrame.filter(productInfoDataFrame.ProductId == eachSuggestion).collect()[0]['ProductName']
      else:
        eachSuggestionProductName = str(eachSuggestion)
      customerProductSuggestDataFrame = customerProductSuggestDataFrame.withColumn(suggestion, F.when((F.col("CustomerId") == eachCustomerProductSuggest.CustomerId)&(F.col("ProductId") == eachCustomerProductSuggest.ProductId), F.lit(eachSuggestionProductName)).otherwise(F.col(suggestion)))
      count += 1   

  previousCustomerId = eachCustomerProductSuggest.CustomerId
```

Any help to direct me is appreciated

Comment: that is such a long code -- can you help us understand your intentions in plain words?

Comment: @samkart I want to rewrite my code to loop each row of dataframe but avoid dataframe.collect()